# 500 Error and Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 when deployed MERN on Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, mern

I have deployed my first MERN application on Heroku. And I get the 500 (Internal Server Error) and SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 when trying to login in my application. Other get request are successful and get 200.
Here is the code of login where the Unexpected token is detected.

```
const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch("/api/users/login", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email,
        password
      })
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setForm({ email: "", password: "" });

        localStorage.setItem("jwt", data.token);
        dispatch(set_loggedUser(data.user));
        dispatch(set_islogged());

        history.push("/");
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the `response`. At least, you can log the response here.

```
.then(
    (response) => 
    {
        console.log(response)
        return response.json()
    })
```